# Place TextView at right of other one and make it always visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

It is easy to place one TextView at right of another TextView but when width on base TextView more than screen size right TextView became not visible.

My XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="Messages" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_r30p0pl10"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_orange"
    android:text="800" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to make right TextView screen even if base TextView width is huge?

UPD:

In other words I need:

If first TextView is short:

```
   |[ShotrTextView][TextView]      |
```

If first TextView is long:

```
   |[LooooooongTextVi...][TextView]|
```

Comment: Take `RelativeLayout` and use `LayoutAlignParentRight`.

Comment: RelativeLayout with LayoutAlignParentRight works like my layout! I need when message is short, right TextView must places at right bound of message, when message is long TextView must places at right screen border!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is TableLayout usage with shrinkColumns = 0

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="0" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Messages" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_r30p0pl10"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_orange"
        android:text="800" />


</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="12345" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as thinking line the only way to do the so...

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium TextMedium TextMedium TextMedium Text"
                android:maxWidth="280dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="HHH"
                 />
```

> And create one [dimension file like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403619/how-to-support-all-the-different-resolutions-of-android-products) and use it.

Comment: What if Device width varies? (240, 320, 480, 720).

Comment: I already said in the answer...Then put all your known width in that dimension file and folder...Simple. :)

Comment: Perfectoo. dint look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer in: [Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/messages" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:ellipsize="end" android:lines="1" android:text="Message" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/counter" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/bg_white_r30p0pl10" android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_orange" android:text="800" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It places right TextView always at right screen border. See screenshot top.

Comment: When message is short, right TextView must places at right bound of message, when message is long TextView must places at right screen border!

Comment: No changes. <TextView
     android:id="@+id/messages"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:lines="1"
     android:text="Messages" />
 

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/counter"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_weight="0"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_white_r30p0pl10"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_orange"
     android:text="800" />

Comment: try to put android:layout_weight="1" to both text views

Comment: Both TextView become equals width and take full screen width