# How to support multiple resolutions and screen sizes in android

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I'm developing an application,which includes displaying html content in WebView.
And now I'm facing the problem of maintaining different resolutions..

I have created Android resolutions for

> 480x800(layout-normal-hdpi)
>
> 720x1184(layout-normal-xhdpi)
>
> 600x1024(layout-large-hdpi) for Samsung GT
>
> 800x1205(layout-large-xhdpi) for Nexus 7

the problem i'm getting is,while testing the samsung GT and Nexus 7 device are taking same resolution specification drawable layout.
i.e..layout-large-hdpi.

can anyone help me, how to remove above drawback.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab (7.0-inch)

Comment: Galaxy Tab (7") doesn't report its real density. To understand this issue, read the following article:
http://realmike.org/blog/2010/12/21/multiple-screen-sizes-with-processing-for-android/

Comment: My answer for same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380885/android-support-multiple-screens/13659340#13659340 . I had a nightmare experience with nexus 7 layouts. Any issue regarding layout designing, I can help

Comment: Thank you.I got the solution.By changing the resolution for samsung GT programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support all the different resolutions of android products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403619/how-to-support-all-the-different-resolutions-of-android-products)

Answer (score 0):

If u designed layouts consistently, no need of defining different `layout` folders(`layout-land`, `layout-large`, `layout-small`) . The `Android OS` will take care of that(regarding `images` display). Only thing you have to do is add the `<support-screens>`  in your `manifest` and below is the  `<support-screens>`:

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

For more information check the Android Developer documents of [Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).