# What is the procedure to designing android screen layout is adapt to all the device screen?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am creating following layout design in android. but it not adapt to all type of screen resolution on different mobile device such as Nexus 4,Nexus 7, 3.2in HVGA slider(ADP1). The layout of the  screen is changes. how to solve the problem. This is my layout code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:padding="20dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="USER LOGIN" android:textColor="#0000ff" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="30dp" android:textSize="32dp" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="NAME"  android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:text=" " android:id="@+id/loginnew_name_editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

    </TableRow>
      <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="AGE   "  android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText android:text=" " android:id="@+id/loginnew_age_editText2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

    </TableRow>
      <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="GENDER"  android:textColor="#ff0000" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:textSize="24dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
           <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:paddingLeft="100dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/loginnew_male_radio0" android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/loginnew_female_radio1"></RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>
          <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ast" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"></ImageView>
          <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="5dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/dora" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>


      </RelativeLayout>


     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <Button android:text="SAVE"  android:id="@+id/loginnew_save_button1" android:textStyle="bold" android:background="@drawable/brand_button_bg" android:textColor="#ffffff00" android:textSize="28dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403619/how-to-support-all-the-different-resolutions-of-android-products and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: This answer will also help u more :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices